# Adding the searchreplace plugin to Umbraco Rich Text Editor

Tags: tinymce, umbraco, umbraco7

The TinyMCE site says to add:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        theme : "advanced",
        mode : "textareas",
        plugins : "searchreplace",
        theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "search,replace" });
```

But I'm not sure how to do this in Umbraco, how can i do it..?
thank you..

Answer (score 1):

While not exactly a duplicate question, I believe you could gain a lot from reviewing the question found here:

[TinyMCE plugin in umbraco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716284/tinymce-plugin-in-umbraco)

Specific to your question, to add the "searchreplace" plugin you will need to add the plugin files to the plugins directory (umbraco_client/tinymce3/plugins/) in a folder named the same as the plugin and edit the tinymce.config file in both the  and  areas

To note, the file added to the plugins directory should be the minified version (all comments and whitespace removed) and titled like plugin_name_src.js